# Rotating a vector triangle around an origin

Tags: c, vector, trigonometry

I've got the following code that's attempting to rotate a triangle around an origin, but for some reason after the code has executed the triangle just becomes warped and I really can't figure it out. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong because I'm using raidans as I should and the triangle is still just becoming warped.

`shipHeading = 120
shipX = 240
shipY = 240`

```
    int shipX = getShipX();
    int shipY = getShipY();
    int shipHeading = getShipHeading();

    float shipHeadingRads = (shipHeading * (PI / 180));

    screen->setCursor(2,40);
    screen->printf("Shipheading: %i, Shipheadingrads: %f", shipHeading, shipHeadingRads);

    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    int x1r, y1r, x2r, y2r, x3r, y3r;

    x1 = shipX;
    y1 = shipY - 20;
    x2 = shipX - 10;
    y2 = shipY + 10;
    x3 = shipX + 10;
    y3 = shipY + 10;

    screen->drawTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, RED);

    //x_rotated = ((x - x_origin) * cos(angle)) - ((y_origin - y) * sin(angle)) + x_origin
  //y_rotated = ((y_origin - y) * cos(angle)) - ((x - x_origin) * sin(angle)) + y_origin

    x1r = ((x1 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y1) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipX;
    y1r = ((shipY - y1) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x1 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;
    x2r = ((x2 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y2) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipX;
    y2r = ((shipY - y2) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x2 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;
    x3r = ((x3 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y3) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipX;
    y3r = ((shipY - y3) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x3 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;
```

Comment: The rotation formula you are using is incorrect.

Comment: What exactly is incorrect? I'm struggling to see it hahaha

Comment: You have a sign error.  Compare to the formulae presented [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: Edit: Got it. Works perfectly now. Thank you for your help.